# QGraphicsItem is not visible after adding to scene

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I'm working on a diagram visualisation tool and I ran into an issue where my `QGraphicsScene` does not display a `shared_ptr<DiagramItem>` when a raw pointer obtained via `.get()` is passed to `scene->addItem()`.
Subsequent check via `scene->items()` shows that my DiagramItem is not a part of the scene. My guess is that it got freed as the refcounter on the `shared_ptr` will be zero after leaving the scope of the testing function...

But that was the testing case. In my actual code I'm using a `shared_ptr` that I got from elsewhere and **is definitely present in memory with a non-zero refcounter**. I get the raw pointer of that and pass it to `scene->addItem()`. It is also not displayed, but this time it **is** present in `scene->items()`. So why is it not being drawn?

If I switch from using `shared_ptr<DiagramItem>` to `DiagramItem*` then the issue disappears and everything is displayed properly. But due to limitations from the rest of the project, I cannot easily abandon smart pointers here, nor do I want to.

Did I run into some kind of memory limitation or am I doing something wrong?

I already tried calling `show()` and `update()` on the item and increasing the scene size in case the item doesn't fit (it does). I also tried breakpointing the `paint()` method, but that one doesn't get called at all.
I found a possibly related question [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/7055/solved-qgraphicsview-item-added-via-additem-not-displaying-in-qgraphicsview/4) where similar behaviour occurs due to the object going out of scope and being deallocated, but that doesn't seem to be the case with my actual `DiagramItem`.

```
class DiagramItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
    ...
}

//Create scene
auto scene = new QGraphicsScene(nullptr);

//Item is created OR obtained from elsewhere
auto item1 = std::make_shared<DiagramItem>(nullptr, QString("aaa"), true);
auto item2 = GetDiagramItem(...);

//Raw pointers get passed to addItem
scene->addItem(item1.get());
scene->addItem(item2.get());

//Item1 is not present at all (directly created DiagramItem)
//Item2 is present but invisible (DiagramItem passed from elsewhere)
//myItem gets Item2
auto myItem = scene->items()[0];
...
```

Comment: it is a bad idea to pass a raw pointer in your case because it breaks the whole idea of shared_ptr. Also, it is not clear what happens to your irem1, item2. Do you store them somewhere or they just temporary variables in a function? in the later case, they get destroyed and raw pointer become invalid.

Comment: Is `itwm1` `item1`, resp. `itwm2` `item2`?

Comment: Sorry about the itwm-item typo, fixed it. Yes, they are the same thing. I tried describing that item2 is stored elsewhere and thus continues to exist after the function ends. As for passing a raw pointer - can it be done any other way? As far as I know, Qt's addItem only accepts a raw pointer.